# How do I make it tell me the date and the number in the same print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program is supposed to show me the date and the number, but I can only get it to tell me the number. What to do?

```
#Ask user when they are leaving for vacation
start = int(input('When are you leaving on your vacation? '))
#Ask user how long they will stay
stay = int(input('How many days will you be gone? '))
#Label days a number starting on sunday at 0
sunday = sunday, 0
monday = monday, 1
tuesday = tuesday, 2
wednesday = wednesday, 3
thursday = thursday, 4
friday = friday, 5
saturday = saturday, 6
#Create varible for print answer
home = ((start+stay)%6) 
#Create print statement
print('You will return on', home) 
#Must make it say "you will return on" saturday, day 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Might make sense to have the list of days as an array/list, so

```py
days = ['sunday', 'monday'...'saturday]
```

Then you can just use f-strings like

```py
print(f'you will return home on {days[home]}, day {home}'
```

The benefit is your index and day of the week have a 1-to-1 relationship, so lists are the simplest way to access both.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so confused.